# Cat 6 STP 4x2x23AWG 500MHz cable earthing without using connectors

Tags: grounding, earth

[image]

Regarding the following wire, I will use this to connect some signal wires between sensors and microcontroller, the only problem being that I will not use any dedicated connectors. Instead, I will be soldering every wire.

How can I put the cover to ground (meaning the GND of the microcontroller) without using connector?

Comment: So the cable has no drain wires for the shields to do that? Please mention cable make and model, preferably a link to datasheet that describes the construction. You can always buy better cable if current one is not suitable.

Comment: Conductive tape could work in a pinch.  Make sure the adhesive is also conductive.

Comment: @Justme I would be glad if you could suggest me one. For the moment I consider suitable any STP or S/FTP cable. I have to mention that I am not very familiar with them, the only specs that I found was the category and then I search on the internet about how are the wires positioned

Comment: Sorry but it is off-topic to ask what to buy or places from where to purchase. You will have to try finding a suitable cable yourself.

Comment: I was asking for a datasheet

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu How could we give you a datasheet without recommending a specific product? Your question sounds as though you already have the cable in hand and you just want to know how to properly connect the shield to ground.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes, that is true, I have the cable but if you give me a good reason I don't mind buying another one.